# Converting A Kivy Program To a Python File?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

**main.py**

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout


kv="""
<RoundedButton@Button>:
    background_color: 0,0,0,0  # the last zero is the critical on, make invisible
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.4,.1,.4,1) if self.state=='normal' else (0,.7,.7,1)  # visual feedback of press
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [(30,30),(30,30),(30,30),(30,30)]
"""
class RoundedButton(Button):
    pass

class grid(MDGridLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.rows=3
        self.cols=3
        self.padding=10
        self.spacing=10
        self.add_widget(RoundedButton(text="12"))
        self.add_widget(RoundedButton(text="12"))
        self.add_widget(RoundedButton(text="12"))
        self.add_widget(RoundedButton(text="12"))
        self.add_widget(RoundedButton(text="12"))

Builder.load_string(kv)

runTouchApp(grid())
```

**Output**

[output of this program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8olL.png)

Here I want the kv string portion to be in the in my RoundedButton
class in python file instead of writing it in kivy format in a string.

Can you tell me how to proceed?

Comment: It's already in a Python file, as a string. What are you hoping to achieve by spelling it out in individual statements, that would still be using the Kivy library? Are you asking how to achieve the end result without using Kivy at all?

Comment: I don't want to use that kv string portion and transfer that whole code to the class of RoundedButton in which I just gave the pass statement...... Thanku

Comment: Actually I need to use a for loop inside RoundedButton class. So I want just to remove the kv string portion and move it to RoundedButton class in which I gave pass statement.

Comment: You didn't explain what you are hoping to achieve. You said you need to use a for loop in the button definition, but that's an XY Problem. You state how you intend to solve a problem (with a for loop) but not what problem you are solving. Have you look at documentation like [this here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords)? That explains how you might go about it.